# Replace the text inside <a> with <img>

Tags: html, jquery

I have this  :

```
<div class="blog-page-nav-previous">
    <a href="my-link" class="blog-link">&lt;&lt;Previous</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to find all instances of the class `blog-page-nav-previous` and replace the text inside the `<a>` tag: `&lt;&lt;Previous` with an image of my own.

How do I do that?

Comment: are you trying to replace the <a> element with an <img> element or place an <img> element inside of the <a> element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace entire HTML content with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335774/how-to-replace-entire-html-content-with-javascript)

Comment: I'm trying to replace the word `<<Previous` with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're asking for a jQuery solution:

```js
// Select all the <a> tags inside .blog-page-nav-previous and change their innerHTML to an <img> tag:
$('.blog-page-nav-previous a').html('<img src="foo.jpg">');
```

```html
<div class="blog-page-nav-previous">
    <a href="my-link" class="blog-link">&lt;&lt;Previous</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
var myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("blog-page-nav-previous");

for (var i = 0; i < myClasses.length; i++) {
  myClasses[i].innerHTML = "<img src='image.jpg'>";
  }
```

```html
<div class="blog-page-nav-previous">
 <a href="my-link" class="blog-link">Previous</a>
</div>
```

If you want the image to have keep the same link as what "Previous" is set as, change the getElementByClassName to look for "my-link" instead of "blog-page-nav-previous"

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response but it is not working. I'm not seeing any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("blog-page-nav-previous");

a.forEach(function(a){
  a.outerHTML = '<img src="images/image.jpg" alt="image">'
});
```

If you are trying to only replace the contents of the  element you could replace a.outerHTML with a.innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the image to work as a link, if yes then I have a solution for you

```
<div class="blog-page-nav-previous">
    <a href="my-link" class="blog-link"><img src="example.png"></a>
</div>
```

This should work and sorry if this is not the answer you want